# object has no attribute 'binary_message'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

so I'm doing a project where we use IBM Bluemix's watson to do some speech to text audio stream stuff, but I've kinda hit a wall. There's one call to a method that really messes everything up and I can't figure out why.

```
import pyaudio
import json
import time
import base64
import threading
import ssl
import numpy as np
from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient
from otherkinds import otherKinds


FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 1000
RECORD_SECONDS = 20
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"
window = np.blackman(CHUNK)

x = 0

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()


class SpeechToTextClient(WebSocketClient):
    def __init__(self):
        ws_url = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

        username = "a9cf87f4-7b1b-4c0a-bc7d-f4100a596a08"
        password = "zBpZmqivDqAl"
        authstring = "{0}:{1}".format(username, password)
        base64string = base64.b64encode(authstring.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

        self.listening = False

        try:
            WebSocketClient.__init__(self, ws_url,
                                 headers=[("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)])
            self.connect()
        except:
            print("Failed to open WebSocket.")

    def opened(self):
        print("opened")
        self.send('{"action": "start", "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=16000"}')
        self.stream_audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream_audio)
        self.stream_audio_thread.start()

    def received_message(self, mensage):
        message = json.loads(str(mensage))
        if "state" in message:
            if message["state"] == "listening":
                self.listening = True
                print('Listening...')

        otherKinds.main_piece(str(mensage))

    def stream_audio(self):
        print("Waiting for Watson")
        while not self.listening:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Connected to Watson")

        while self.listening:

            for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * 2)):
                data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)

                try:
                    self.send(bytearray(data), binary=True)
                except ssl.SSLError:
                    pass

            self.send('{"action": "stop"}')
            time.sleep(1)

    def close(self):
        self.listening = False
        self.stream_audio_thread.join()
        WebSocketClient.close(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    # Here is where we will merge the audio part

    stt_client = SpeechToTextClient()
    while (1):
        pass
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

This is the part that totally goofs everything up:

```
otherKinds.main_piece(str(mensage))
```

and this is the error message it gives me:

```
File "C:\Users\jared\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()

File "C:\Users\jared\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:/Users/jared/PycharmProjects/smartAssistant/testreciord.py", line 70, in stream_audio
self.send(bytearray(data), binary=True)

File "C:\Users\jared\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ws4py\websocket.py", line 299, in send
message_sender = self.stream.binary_message if binary else self.stream.text_message
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'binary_message'
```

I've got no idea what happening here, it works fine if I take the call out, but thats the only thing messing it up. It doesn't matter if the method is in the same file, not in a class or whatever. Any help would be great, thanks! :D

Comment: The traceback is caused by `self.stream` being `None` inside the websocket library. How are you connecting `stream` to your `stt_client` inside `__main__`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I actually figured out the issue. Before it would work just fine as long as the method call wasn't there, so it would connect and do everything i needed. I'm not entirely sure what I changed, but I've got it working now :D